# Passing from ajax to fetch on client side with a glassfish server

Tags: ajax, glassfish, fetch

I have a phonegap application that uses

```
$.ajax(
  type: 'POST,
  dataType:"json",
  url: 'test.com'
  data: { mail: 'bob@test.com' }
)
```

which i get in my glassfish server doing something like

```
HttpServletRequest request;
request.getParameter('mail');
```

I'm moving my application in react native so i tryed

```
fetch('test.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  },
  body: 'mail=bob@test.com',
})
```

and i tryed

```
fetch('test.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ mail: 'bob@test.com' }),
})
```

but neither of these worked, i'm deseperately having request.getParameter('mail') == null on server side.
How can i do ?
Note : i don't want to change the way the server handles things.

Comment: are you trying on ios or android?

Comment: I'm trying on android, but does it make a difference ?

Comment: no it should not, but on ios you will get error if your url doesn't start with https